# What is the difference between binding data in data grid view methods?

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between binding data in data grid view methods ??

```
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnUserName" runat="server" 
   Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"UserFirstName")%>'
                                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' OnClick="lnkBtnUserName_Click" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
```

and this second one

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee ID">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lblempid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmpId.EmpId") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

means in

**method 1**

```
Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"UserFirstName")%>'
          CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserID") %>'
```

**method 2**

```
Text='<%# Bind("EmpId.EmpId")
```

also explain use one this   `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserID")` in 1st one ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call such as `Eval("UserID")` corresponds to `TemplateControl.Eval` method call and that itself actually translates into call such as `DataBinder.Eval(GetDataItem(), "UserID")`. In summary, Eval is shorthand syntax for DataBinder.Eval - that internally inspects first argument and based on its type, it will try to resolve the second argument over it - for example, for data row, it will try to resolve to a column name while for plain objects, it will use reflection to resolve to property name.

`Bind` is special syntax that results into bi-directional binding used when editing i.e. control will get value from data source (similar to Eval) and it will also update (modified) value back to data source. AFAIK, Bind does not correspond to a method call (as Eval) but instead ASP.NET compiler would spit the necessary code to ensure  two way data binding.

See data binding expressions overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx